# why show undefined variable when pass frontend

Tags: laravel, undefined-variable

When I pass a variable in the fronted site it shows that the variable is `undefined`: why does this happen? I've also tried using compact but it does not work for me. Is there any way to solve the problem?

`HomeController` file code:

```php
public function index()
    {
        $category =DB::table('categories')->where('status', 1)->get();
        $brand =DB::table('brands')->where('status', 1)->get();
        $home=view('home.main_content');
        return view('home')->with('home', $home)->with('category', $category);
    }
```

Fronted code using a `foreach` loop:

```php
@foreach($category as $result)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#">{{$result->name}}</a></h4>
    </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Error:

```
Undefined variable: category (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelblog\resources\views\home\sidebar_left.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is called `home` and the view in which you are trying to use the variable is called `sidebar_left`.

So if you use the blade `@include` directive to load that view you will need to pass the variable to that view. 
You can do that like this:

```
@include('sidebar_left', ['category' => $category])
```

Then you will be able to use it.